# Neura SDK implementation on android

Tags: android, machine-learning, geolocation, location, neura

Is Neura SDK a Geofencing SDK? I am developing an Android application that will allow users to rent their parking spots on hourly basis and promoting efficient parking management.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is Yes, but to answer in detail, the Neura SDK is trying to look beyond geofence and understand the semantic meaning of a location to a user e.g. Home, work, activity zone. In any of the given semantic locations that the Neura SDK can identify, you can be notified when a user arrives or leaves these locations. The methodology of doing this goes way beyond just a simple geofence and works a lot more reliably with less of a performance impact on the phone.

Visit the [Neura Devsite](https://dev.theneura.com) for more details.